# How to implement this margin for UITableViewCell via layers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, calayer

I need to implement this left margin for the background of the cell.

Now I tried to do it this way - but the result is not correct - the content of the cell is moving with the margin. How can I solve an issue?

```
CGRect layerFrame = self.layer.frame;
layerFrame.size.width -= kRightLayerMargin;
layerFrame.origin.x += kLeftLayerMargin;
self.layer.frame = layerFrame;

self.layer.backgroundColor = [[SCUtils cellSelectionColor] CGColor];
self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Implement your cell's `layoutSubviews` method as follows:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    //have the cell layout normally
    [super layoutSubviews];
    //get the bounding rectangle that defines the position and size of the textLabel
    CGRect textLabelFrame = [[self textLabel] frame];
    //anchor it to the top-left corner
    textLabelFrame.origin = CGPointMake(kLeftLayerMargin, textLabelFrame.origin.y);

    //set the textLabel frame (this will move+resize it)
    [[self textLabel] setFrame:textLabelFrame];

    //reposition the other controls accordingly
}
```